# vb.net NAudio.dll - Type 'AudioFileReader' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, naudio

(Visual Studio 2019)

It seems I have run into a snag.
My sample code is this.

```
Imports NAudio.Wave
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Dim filename As String
        filename = "G:\VS_Lessons\Media\Read\01. Got to Choose.mp3
        Dim reader As New AudioFileReader(filename)
        Dim duration As String = reader.TotalTime.ToString("mm\:ss")
        reader.Dispose()
        Label1.Text = duration
    End Sub
End Class
```

This only happens when I am running the site LIVE and NOT from VS.
Running it through VS, it works as it supposed to.
Running it from a live URL it gives the following error.

```
Type 'AudioFileReader' is not defined
```

On this line

```
Dim reader As New AudioFileReader(filename)
```

Now, I tried to register the NAudio.dll using. (The NAudio.dll file is in the BIN folder of the website)

```
gacutil -i NAudio.dll
```

However, I get the following line

```
Failure adding assembly to the cache: Attempt to install an assembly without a strong name
```

I followed the steps in this article here 
[How to add Strong Name to an existing DLL and install to the GAC](http://codeingaddiction.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-add-strong-name-to-existing-dll_16.html)

But I get a **FAILURE** when trying to create the DLL file on **STEP 5**. (Maybe I am doing it wrong because I am not the owner of the file. Not really sure, this is the first time I have ever done anything like this and was trying everything I could find online)

Any assistance on this would be mighty grateful.

Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website has to be converted into an Application.
**IIS** | **Web Site** |
**Right-click** on the web site name or sub-folder name
And choose [**Convert to Application**]
Run the script, and it works.

Now, I have to do this on the live site, but first, I will do the local site, as it runs the same script, and I will get all the bugs out of it, then I can do the LIVE IIS site.

Answer (score 0):

It Could Be Due To `Partial Class` Instead Of `Public Class`. Or You Haven't Downloaded Genuine DLL Version Of NAudio.

If Its Problem 1 ( *Due To Use Of **Partial Class*** ) Then Change To `Public Class`

If Its Problem 2 ( *Use Of Non-Genuine **NAudio DLL*** ) Then Download [NAudio From Here](https://www.dll-files.com/naudio.dll.html)

If Problem Still Persists, Then It Would Be For Windows Form Application.